# With a linear representation, how does the continuity of $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ relate to that of $G \times V \to V$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, topological-groups

I'm currently reading *Traces of Hecke Operators* by Knightly and Li, while simultaneously revisiting the adelic/representation-theoretic point of view on automorphic forms.

In Knightly and Li, they give a familiar definition of a representation. That is, for a locally compact group $G$ and a normed vector space $V$, they note that a representation is a homomorphism
$$ \pi: G \longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V) $$
such that the map
$$\begin{align}
G \times V &\longrightarrow V \\
(g,v) &\mapsto \pi(g)v
\end{align}$$
is continuous. Sometimes I've seen this stated first in terms of the continuity of $g \mapsto \pi(g)v$.

But I note that both $G$ and $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ are topological groups, so it would make sense to consider the continuity of $\pi$ directly as a function $G \longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$. I don't know how the continuity of $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ relates to the continuity of $G \times V \to V$.

Intuitively, I suspect that the continuity of $G \times V \to V$ implies continuity of the representation map $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$, but not the converse. Is this right?

Comment: Ben Steinberg has implicitly pointed this out in the comment to his answer, but just for sake of clarifying the question: when you say GL(V) is a topological group which topology are you choosing? I ask because in your setup you mention V veing a normed vector space and so I wondered if you were thinking of GL(V) with the subspace topology inherited from ${\mathcal B}(V)$, in which case things usually go wrong.

Comment: @YemonChoi I had originally thought about the subspace topology indeed, but I hadn't even considered the strong operator topology. I now gather that in the subspace topology, continuity of $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ does not guarantee continuity of $G \times V \to V$, but I' not certain of this yet. I intend to examine the reference given by Ben later.

Comment: Yup, one way to see that things go wrong is to look at ${\bf R}$ acting on $L^2({\bf R})$ by left translations. Then for any $t>0$ you can find some norm-one vector $\xi$ in $L^2({\bf R})$ such that $\Vert  \lambda_t\xi - \xi \Vert \geq 2$, and so $\Vert \lambda_0 - \lambda_t \Vert \geq 2$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: I'm not an analyst but many years ago I was interested in representations of compact monoids for some reason and so I read up on this basic stuff and saw that more or less everybody uses the strong operator topology.  I vaguely remember that if $V$ is a Banach space you may only need that $g\mapsto \pi(g)v$ is continuous for each $v$ but I don't remember where I saw that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For locally compact groups continuity of $\pi$, joint continuity of the action map $G\times V\to V$ and separate continuity in both variables are equivalent.  See Theorem 2.3 of Karl H. Hofmann, Sidney A. Morris
The Structure of Compact Groups (edition 3).

Comment: For continuity of $\pi$ I am giving $GL(V)$ the strong operator to topology

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the reference.